# Unable to Login to my Joomla Site

Tags: joomla-3.x, login

Am unable to login to my joomla site al of the sudden despite having the right credentials. I have changed the password via my phpadmin but in Vain. I tested it with wrong/non existent logins and am able to get the error message that username/password are not valid. However when I use valid logins, the site just refreshes and brings back the login panel. I have cross checked my configuration file and all looks okay.

Some one please help out.

Comment: Are you sure it's not something simple like having CAPS enabled? Are you getting anything in the PHP error log?

Comment: CAPs is not enabled

Comment: What was the last change you did to your Joomla site, if any?

Comment: @SheldonSeale Nothing, I was logging in as usual.

Comment: Then I suspect you have been hacked. Myjoomla is a service that can detect and correct hacked sites. They (https://myjoomla.com) will allow you to do an initial scan of your site for free. Their clean up service is ranked very well and I have heard that it is well worth it. I would run the scan...

Comment: @SheldonSeale myJoomla have to be installed - a plugin, to get access

Comment: @KlintWeb There are ways myJoomla.com can be manually installed - it doesnt need to be installed by logging in and uploading. Please contact me for full details and support at https://myjoomla.com/contact

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it before.

Sometimes it was enough to delete files from the browser cache. Sometimes another browser and sometimes to set set the cookie domain and path in the configuration.php

Answer (score 0):

Probably your IP is banned. Change IP (use a vpn or restart your router) and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling that your website is hacked. The first step you can take to see if you can regain access is to restore the Joomla! installation by using the files in full stable installation package that you can download from [the downloads archive for Joomla! 3](https://downloads.joomla.org/cms/joomla3). Please keep in mind to download the same version as is currently installed, you don't want to upgrade right away, just restore.

Unzip the file and upload everything except for the "installation" directory, because you don't want to get started over with a fresh installation. Use the merge option in your FTP client to make sure the third party extensions will remain.

After uploading is complete, check if you can login again. There is a big chance that the malicious code is partially removed, so that you can use the backend again.